# Remove user from Google Compute Engine instances

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil, google-cloud-platform

I'm using gcutil to access Google Compute Engine instances.

I noticed that when I spin up a new instance, the new instance has a user that I used on a previous machine in this project.

I want to remove that user - not just from this machine, which of course I can do via the normal *nix processes, but, I want to ensure it is not used for any future Compute Engine instances.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, once a user has run the **gcloud auth login** command and authenticated with the cloud project, their ssh key is added to the projects Compute Engine **Common metadata**, stored under the **sshKeys** key/value pair, these are then inherited by all instances within the project, providing access to login via ssh to the instances.

To prevent an existing user from having ssh permissions on a projects instances you will need to modify this value, keeping only the public keys of the users you wish to have access. This can be found in the **Cloud Console** within you project, under **Compute Engine** and then **Metadata**. In your case the all *users* may be you, just logged in from different clients.

However you cannot modify the existing metadata from there, you need to use the **gcutil setcommoninstancemetadata** command, to re-insert the modified sshKeys value (see https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#common), from my experimentation this appears to reset **ALL** common metadata for the project, so if you have more than just the default sshKeys set on your project, you will need to add them back in at the same time from the command line.